# Sort Array element by its values

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have an array elements which need to sort and make selected element into top of array.

```
[{
    parent_email: 'dsa@hsah.com',
    id: 143,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com',
    id: 210,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'ffff@gmail.com',
    id: 225,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'fam@gmail.com',
    id: 221,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'fggfdfg@gmail.com',
    id: 224,
    unreadCount: 0 
 }]
```

i have another array by which above array element need to sort. first element is on top second is on second position third is on third position and so on.

```
[{ 
    parent_id: 'fam@gmail.com'
 },
 { 
    parent_id: 'ffff@gmail.com'
 },
 { 
    parent_id: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com'
 }]
```

my result array should be like

```
[{
    parent_email: 'fam@gmail.com',
    id: 221,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'ffff@gmail.com',
    id: 225,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com',
    id: 210,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'dsa@hsah.com',
    id: 143,
    unreadCount: 0 
 },
 {
    parent_email: 'fggfdfg@gmail.com',
    id: 224,
    unreadCount: 0 
 }]
```

i have tried but it only sort single element not more then one.

```
for (var i = array2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
array1.sort(function(x,y){
    return x.parent_email == rows[i].parent_id ? -1 : y.parent_email ==  rows[i].parent_id ? 1 : 0; 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems not exactly like sorting (as you grab matching items in desired order and don't care about the order of the rest), so you may go, like (though, it may produce unexpected output in case of duplicating e-mails):

```js
const src = [
  {parent_email: 'fam@gmail.com', id: 221, unreadCount: 0},
  {parent_email: 'ffff@gmail.com', id: 225, unreadCount: 0},
  {parent_email: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com', id: 210, unreadCount: 0},
  {parent_email: 'dsa@hsah.com', id: 143, unreadCount: 0},
  {parent_email: 'fggfdfg@gmail.com', id: 224, unreadCount: 0}
];
const order = [
  {parent_id: 'fam@gmail.com'},
  {parent_id: 'ffff@gmail.com'},
  {parent_id: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com'}
];
const res = order
  .map(item => src.find(entry => entry.parent_email == item.parent_id))
  .concat(src.filter(entry => !order.map(item => item.parent_id).includes(entry.parent_email)));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should sort the first array by the index in the second array:

```
 const emailRank = new Map();
 for(const [index, { parent_id }] of array2.entries())
   emailRank.set(parent_id, index);

 array1.sort((a, b) => emailRank.get(b.parent_email) - emailRank.get(a.parentEmail));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sort in lodash

```
_.sortBy( parent_email, [function(o) { return o.parent_email; }]);
```

Comment: beware, you are not using the array with `parent_id`

Comment: i am just giving info. just change it for Parent_id if you want it

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    parent_email: 'dsa@hsah.com',
    id: 143,
    unreadCount: 0
  },
  {
    parent_email: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com',
    id: 210,
    unreadCount: 0
  },
  {
    parent_email: 'ffff@gmail.com',
    id: 225,
    unreadCount: 0
  },
  {
    parent_email: 'fam@gmail.com',
    id: 221,
    unreadCount: 0
  },
  {
    parent_email: 'fggfdfg@gmail.com',
    id: 224,
    unreadCount: 0
  }
]
const orderBy = [{
    parent_id: 'fam@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    parent_id: 'ffff@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    parent_id: 'sumanaqqq@ius.com'
  }
]
const length = data.length
const dataOrders = orderBy.reduce((result, item, index) => (result[item.parent_id] = index + 1) && result, {})
const dataOrdered = data.sort((a, b) => (dataOrders[a.parent_email] || length) - (dataOrders[b.parent_email] || length))
console.log(dataOrdered)
```